# Entity framework one to many relationship parentobject is null in child while parentID is set

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I've got a problem with EF which I can't seem to solve. Like the title says it I've got a one to many relationship. When I want to retrieve the parentobject from the child I get Nothing(vb.net);

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

while the parentobjectID is set in the childobject.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Turning lazy loading off, didn't help.
2. Checking the foreignkey is set correct in the database 10 times.
3. Checking in the edmx model if the multiplicity of the parent child
   is correct also 10 times.
4. Tried to cheat in a partial class by creating a context and
   retrieving the correct parentobject by the parentID. Which gave me
   another error that made sense;

   > The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because
   >   they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

And I need to say this child has another parent which is set correct.

Code Auto generated class TestStepPageElement

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Partial Public Class TestStepPageElement
    Public Property TestStepPageElementID As System.Guid
    Public Property PageElementID As System.Guid
    Public Property TestStepID As System.Guid
    Public Property Order As Integer

    Public Overridable Property PageElement As PageElement
    Public Overridable Property TestStep As TestStep
    Public Overridable Property TestStepPageElementParameters As ICollection(Of TestStepPageElementParameter) = New HashSet(Of TestStepPageElementParameter)

End Class
```

Auto generated code parent

```
Imports System
    Imports System.Collections.Generic

    Partial Public Class PageElement
        Public Property PageElementID As System.Guid
        Public Property FriendlyName As String
        Public Property Type As TestMonkey.Shared.Enumerations.PageElementType
        Public Property PageID As System.Guid
        Public Property Description As String
        Public Property IdentifierType As TestMonkey.Shared.Enumerations.PageElementIdentifierType
        Public Property IdentifierOptions As String
        Public Property IsDeleted As Boolean

        Public Overridable Property Page As Page
        Public Overridable Property TestStepPageElements As ICollection(Of TestStepPageElement) = New HashSet(Of TestStepPageElement)

    End Class
```

Here is the partial class of TestStepPageElement where the Me.PageElement is nothing

```
    Partial Public Class TestStepPageElement

    ''' <summary>Converts the object to info</summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function ToTestStepPageElementInfo() As [Shared].TestStepPageElementInfo

        Dim objInfo As New [Shared].TestStepPageElementInfo() With
            {
                .TestStepPageElementID = Me.TestStepPageElementID,
                .TestStepID = Me.TestStepID,
                .PageID = Me.PageElement.PageID,
                .PageElementID = Me.PageElementID,
                .PageElementFriendlyName = Me.PageElement.FriendlyName,
                .PageElementType = Me.PageElement.Type,
                .PageElementIdentifierType = Me.PageElement.IdentifierType,
                .PageElementIdentifierOptions = Me.PageElement.IdentifierOptions,
                .Order = Me.Order,
                .VariableNames = (From tspep In Me.TestStepPageElementParameters
                                  Order By tspep.Order
                                  Select tspep.VariableName).ToArray()
            }

        Return objInfo

    End Function

End Class

Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Reflection
```

Here's where this partial class is called

```
''' <summary></summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Partial Class TestStep

    ''' <summary>Converts the test step to info</summary>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Function ToTestStepInfo() As [Shared].TestStepInfo

        Dim objInfo As New [Shared].TestStepInfo() With
            {
                .TestStepID = Me.TestStepID,
                .FullStepText = Me.FullStepText,
                .Order = Me.Order,
                .PageID = Me.PageID,
                .ReferencedTestID = Me.ReferencedTestID,
                .ReferencedTestParameters = Me.ReferencedTestParameter.Select(Function(rtp) rtp.ToReferencedTestParameterInfo()).ToArray(),
                .Type = Me.Type,
                .TestStepSetDimensions = Me.TestStepSetDimensions.Select(Function(tssd) tssd.ToTestStepSetDimensionInfo()).ToArray(),
                .TestStepPageElements = (From tspe In Me.TestStepPageElements
                                        Order By tspe.Order
                                        Select tspe.ToTestStepPageElementInfo()).ToArray()
            }

        Return objInfo
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Please post some code...

Comment: can you post some code illustrating the class generated from the edmx?

Comment: this doesn't show any database retrieval code at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry guys, I feel stupid. It appears a new object was being created with no value for the PageElement property. Thanks for trying to help!